# How to attach labels (from user defined variables) to jmeter response data?

Tags: jmeter

I want to compare results of two sql queries of the following type

```
select count(*) from X where userid='${userid}'
```

where X is some subquery (different in both actual queries). 
I want to check whether both of these queries return the same resultset using jmeter.
Hence, I created two jdbc requests in the thread group, and I supply the userids through a set of 50 userids stored in a csv file. All this works fine.
The core problem is that I have two samplers in a thread group, and I want to compare their results. I came across a similar question, which suggests to use a post-processor to store the response into a file. 
However, being a newbie in JMeter, I could only manage to create 2 post-processors (1 for each request ) which write "prev.getResponseDataAsString()" to different files. 
I get the following output, in one of the files

```
1
0

1
0

1
93583

1
42456

1
37033

1
37033

1
93583
```

It is clear from this result, that I have no idea which thread produced which result in the file, which brings me to my question.
How do I attach labels to jmeter response data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store result sets into a [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and use i.e. [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) or [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) to compare two variable values. Depending on response data type the approaches may differ.

Check out [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article to learn how to work with JDBC test elements results, if anything remains unclear update your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sampler called a "Debug Sampler" 
And a counter config in your threads, so for each thread the count is incremented
If you add that debug sampler and change the title to "Debug printout Thread ${counterThread}" 
Then that will show up in your view results tree